# trying to add a checkbox dynamically with jquery but nothing apepars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just trying to create a very basic to-do app and for whatever reason, my checkboxes are not showing up.

html:

```
<div class="todo-box">
    <input id="first-contact" type="text" placeholder="what do you have to do?"></input>
    <button>submit</button>
    <div id="list-section">
    </div>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var a = $('#first-contact').val().toLowerCase();
    $('<p>').attr('class', 'list-item').append(a).appendTo('#list-section'); 
    $('<input>', {type: "checkbox"}).appendTo('#list-item');

    var pAmount = $('#list-section').children().length;
    if (pAmount > 6) {
        $('#list-section p').last().remove();
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Where is your p element? Are you wanting to create a new `<p>` with the checkbox in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues in `$('<input>', {type: "checkbox"}).appendTo('#list-item');`:

- you're using `{type: "checkbox"}` at the place where jQuery `$()` expects a domain argument: you must build a complete element in first argument instead
- you're appending the element to a `list-item` **id** while you created it as a **class**

This will work:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var a = $('#first-contact').val().toLowerCase();
    $('<p>').attr('class', 'list-item').append(a).appendTo('#list-section'); 
    $('<input type="checkbox">').appendTo('.list-item:last');

    var pAmount = $('#list-section').children().length;
    if (pAmount > 6) {
        $('#list-section p').last().remove();
    }

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-box">
    <input id="first-contact" type="text" placeholder="what do you have to do?"></input>
    <button>submit</button>
    <div id="list-section">
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: modified in response to the OP's comment : added `:last` modifier to make checkbox added to the just newly created item only.

Comment: thank you so much! this did fix my issue, but now I have another one.  Every time a todo is added, a new checkbox appears, for EVERY todo. So If I have two todos the original one will now have two checkboxes and the new one I added will have one...until I add another todo.  Then the original will have three, the last one will have two, and my new todo will have one.  How do I limit the checkboxes?

Comment: @kmgiffin You're right. Didn't pay attention to that! Now corrected: look at my modified code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are going for?

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

    var a = $('#first-contact').val().toLowerCase();

   // update here
    $('#list-section').append("<p><input type='checkbox' value='"+a+"'></p>");

    var pAmount = $('#list-section').children().length;
    if (pAmount > 6) {
        $('#list-section p').last().remove();
    }

});
```